# TextFormField Cursor bubble and scrolling issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, cursor, vertical-scrolling, flutter-textformfield

When scrolling the page, Cursor bubble overlap the other widgets and `Appbar`. Can you help me?

**This GIF file shows my issue**
[image: This GIF file shows my issue.]

**Widget**

```dart
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  Sample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: false,
      extendBody: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('AppBar'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView(
              addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  height: 70,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'This part want not be scrolled',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Scrollbar(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  children: [
                    Table(
                      children: [
                        TableRow(children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [Text('Name')],
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration())
                            ],
                          )
                        ]),
                        TableRow(
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              children: [Text('Name')],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration())
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        TableRow(
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              children: [Text('Name')],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration())
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        TableRow(
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              children: [Text('Name')],
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration())
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table` widget is made for non-scrollable `GridView`. It renders full `Table` widget tree once and keep its children  alive. You can think it is similar like `SingleChildScrollView`. Here in your `Table` children generate only once and don't call dispose even though it is not visible on screen, and it is the nature of `Table` Widget. To test this, you create a statefullWidget and pass it to  column children.

For more

- [Table (Flutter Widget of the Week)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lbE0wsVZSw)
- [Table-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html)

**Solution**
you can simply use `ListView.Builder`

Comment: Thank you. You Answer is correct. When I remove the table, it run perfectly

Comment: What about when this happens in a SingleChildScrollView? You would not want to have to put every TextField that scrolls inside a ListView.builder.

Comment: *What about when this happens in a SingleChildScrollView?* Depends on inner widget.